# jQuery Mobile - pageinit handler not called on subsequent changePage calls

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two jquery mobile "pages" (divs designated as pages) on the html page.  I want to call methods every time I go to a page. I hook up methods to fire on ['pageinit'](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) event. However, it only gets called once and doesn't get called on subsequent changePage calls.

Here is a [jsFiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/CqRzQ/9/). ( time stamp should change on pageinit )

Here is my code in entirety https://gist.github.com/dev-e-loper/5356942

My pages:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
     <h1>One</h1>
 <a id="page1_link" data-role="button">go to page 2</a>

    <div id="page1_output"></div>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
     <h1>Two</h1>
 <a id="page2_link" data-role="button">go to page 1</a>

    <div id="page2_output"></div>
</div>
```

Code to hook up pageinit handlers:

```
$("#page1").live('pageinit', function () {
    $("#page1_output").append('<br/> page 1 initialized. time - ' + new Date());
});


$("#page2").live('pageinit', function () {
    $("#page2_output").append('<br/> page 2 initialized time - ' + new Date());
});


$("#page1_link").live('click', function () {

    $.mobile.changePage($("#page2"));

});

$("#page2_link").live('click', function () {

    $.mobile.changePage($("#page1"));

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pageinit` will fire when your page first loads. Both of your pages are cached within the DOM so that event will only fire once. Try `pageshow` which will fire each time the page is shown.

Also, `live()` is depreciated. You should use `bind()` or `on()`.

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

```
$("#page1").bind('pageshow', function () {
    $("#page1_output").append('<br/> page 1 initialized. time - ' + new Date());
});


$("#page2").bind('pageshow', function () {
    $("#page2_output").append('<br/> page 2 initialized time - ' + new Date());
});
```

Comment: you would think binding to  `pageload` event would work but it doesn't. `pageshow` works though

Comment: as far as `on` function, the page is using jquery 1.6.4 so it's not available. i'll upgrade jquery and use `on' instead. thanks

Comment: I have no idea how they came up with the page event names but `pageload` could also be confusing. Was the page loaded from cache or from the server? Glad I was able to solve your issue.