# JQuery mobile - click event only fires on current page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function (event) {
        alert("pageinit called");               
        $('#logout').bind('click', function() {alert("clicked!");});
    });
```

The first time the page runs you get a single alert 'pageinit called'. Clicking the element with id #logout fires the alert 'clicked!'. If I click any other links in this page I still get the 'pageinit called' alert (and I get it multiple times, apparently for each page I have previously navigated as well) but subsequently the handler for #logout is gone and never never re-established.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the handler for #logout to remain? I've tried:

```
$('#logout').die('click').live('click', function() {alert("clicked!");});
```

to no avail.

Comment: take a look at this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933134/jquery-mobile-pageinit-handler-not-called-on-subsequent-changepage-calls

Comment: yea I saw that and a few others that sound similar to my situation. Aside from what I mentioned in my op, I've tried handling various page events, tried turning off jqm DOM caching. None of it works!

Comment: this one might work for you because of the conditional checks..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451814/how-to-attach-a-event-to-a-jquery-mobile-page-using-on-and-off

Comment: Pageinit will fire once for each page, logout button as well. It looks like #logout id is duplicated in all your pages. That's causing the problem.

Comment: @Omar that's what I was thinking after looking at it more. I'll try to iterate through or something like that.

Comment: @Omar what work around would you suggest?

Comment: try this 1) bind `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () { $(this).find('#logout').on('click', function () { code here }); });` and 2) unbind  `$(document).on('pagebeforehide', function () { $(this).find('#logout').off('click'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more closely (and as commented by Omar), this problem is caused by a combination of the jquery mobile paging system AND *trying to attach to a 'single' element by id.*

In my case each time I clicked a link within the page it would load into the jqm paging system  a separate page, each one containing its own #logout element. My solution was to query for all the buttons and attach handlers to each one:

```
var buttons = $("*[id='logout']");

buttons.each(function() {
    // handle click or whatever here
});
```

Instead of:

```
var button = $('#logout'); // Only hooks into the first #logout element
```